# Why getElementsByClass does not work in jsoup?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to get some elements by their class names. Here is the HTML file:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="page_clips">
        <div id="content" class="margin-right-5">
            <div class="product-grid margin-left-5">
                <div>.....</div>
                <div>.....</div>
                <div>.....</div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, what i want to get is, the div that has the class="product-grid margin-left-5".
Here is what i do:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
Element page_clips = doc.getElementById("page_clips");
Element page_clip_content = page_clips.getElementById("content");
```

This piece of code succesfully gets the div with the id "content". Then when i try,

```
Elements elementsIWantToGet= page_clip_content.getElementsByClass("product-grid margin-left-5");
```

it returns empty. What am i doing wrong? Isn't the name of the class attribute of that div is "product-grid margin-left-5" ? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`getElementsByClass`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByClass%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't support multiple class names. By giving it `"product-grid margin-left-5"`, do you mean to find all elements with *both* classes? Or *either* class?

Either way, use [`select`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29), which accepts CSS selectors:

For elements with *both*:

```
.. = page_clip_content.select(".product-grid.margin-left-5");
```

For elements with *either*:

```
.. = page_clip_content.select(".product-grid, .margin-left-5");
```

Comment: thank you, both solutions work for me but there i had to make a slight modification. When i look at the html source on the page, the class name has product-grid, but when i get it with jsoup, i see that the calss name has product-list, not product-grid. This seems weird to me, do you have ant idea why that is happening?

Comment: @panpa: Sounds like the page has JavaScript on it that changes the class.